# Entity Framework not playing nicely with Oracle

Tags: oracle, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have implemented a web service that uses some extremely simple linq queries using Entity Framework attaching to an Oracle 11g database.  This works fine locally running in visual studio.  When I deploy this web service to our development box it is not working.  First I was getting an error that:

*The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.*

I did some research and read some posts about modifying the web.config (or the machine.config) to have this entry:

```
  <system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

I chose to put it in the web.config.  After I did that, I started getting the error:

*Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.0.50727, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)*

I then decided to install odp.net on the server.  After that I started getting the error:

*An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.data: Column 'InvariantName' is constrained to be unique. Value 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client' is already present. (D:\Duke\SmartGridWS\web.config line 107)*

This of course led me to check the machine.config, and sure enough, the odp.net install put the same entry in the machine.config  So, now I have removed the duplicate web.config entry and am simply getting this error:

*The underlying provider failed on Open.*

Here is my connection string entry in my web.config:

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EDMS.csdl|res://*/EDMS.ssdl|res://*/EDMS.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=EDMSPT01;PASSWORD=*redacted*;USER ID=*redacted*&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Pretty stumped here.  Mad props to the wizard who knows what is going on here.